# windows explorer is opening behind of my wpf application when i used Process.Start("explorer.exe", path);

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wpf

I am trying to open a local window location with selected file on button click its opening correctly but its opening behind of my WPF application.
I am using this below code:

```
string path = @"/n,/e,/select,C:"+@"\jre.txt";
Process.Start("explorer.exe", path2);
```

also its open multiple window explorer on each click.

Comment: `Process.Start(@"c:\jre.txt");`

Comment: No it is  Process.Start("explorer.exe", path);

Comment: yes but i want to highlight file name  also when location will open for this am using @"/n,/e,/select

Answer (score 0):

Just tried and works for me (on WinForms).

Declaring first of course `using System.Diagnostics;`, then in the code i just tried (with my files, but the idea is just the same) `Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"/n,/e,/select,writeherethefullpathofthefilewithoutthe@symbol");`. For me, it opens the folder and selects the file, being the folder on focus and not my app. Tested on Win10 with VS2019.

Comment: its not working on my case its not focus on folder path . also multiple instance of window is opening in each button click.